# CSPRNG Python 2.7 implementation

Tags: python, random

How can I implement a CSPRNG algorithm in python 2.7?

In python 3.6 there is the secrets module, but I have not found anything for python 2.7

Comment: Right when you open the documentation of the [`random` module for python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) you can see highlighted in red: **Warning The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. Use [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) or [`SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.** You cannot find anything if you don't even try to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the os.urandom() and andom.SystemRandom class to secure random generator in Python 2

Get systemRandom instance out of random class.

Example of systemRandom:-

```
import random
systemRandom = random.SystemRandom()
SystemRandom.randint()
randomNumber=systemRandom.randint(1,30)
```

Example of os.urandom

```
import os
import struct
print(struct.unpack('i', os.urandom(4)))
print(struct.unpack('i', os.urandom(4)))
```

Refer to [this](https://pynative.com/cryptographically-secure-random-data-in-python/) to get started with CSPRNG.

Comment: @ Mark Dickinson Edited according to help section

Comment: In *Example of systemRandom*, it seems there is a typo at line 3 (`systemRandom.randint()`). Anyway, I am getting this error `TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 0):

> cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (CSPRNG)

```
>>> import random
>>> random.SystemRandom().randint(2**128, 2**(128+1))
414898192462243312770563947893545439929L
>>> 
>>> random.SystemRandom().randint(2**128, 2**(128+1))
551865749877602333306492786340710356728L
>>> 
>>> random.SystemRandom().randint(2**128, 2**(128+1))
536575901254084412494463427722820032319L
```